Ubuntu web crawler in my local network
I am currently living in a shared house. Today I ran an nmap scan just out of curiosity. Then I found that it has two Ubuntu servers running. One runs phpmyadmin and has ssh, http and mysql, and the other one runs a web crawler? with only ssh.
Here is the screenshot of the results.

Do you have any clue what these are for?

You should ask your house mate running these servers.

The fritz box is likely your DSL/Cable box. Whoever administers it likely knows the answers to these questions. You'll probably find a picture of it, and specification on this page: https://en.avm.de/products/fritzbox/

You found 2 running computers, one with IP 192.168.178.138 and the other with IP 192.168.178.164.
For 192.168.178.138, this device might be running a web server (HTTP) and a MySQL database, possibly indicating a web application or database server.
For 192.168.178.164, only SSH is open, which suggests it's likely a server or machine that can only be accessed remotely via secure shell.
If you have concerns about security you need to talk to the admin of these computers.
